# How to use jTable to retrieve data from database

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I am new to java. I am trying to write a code for search which should retrieve that particular searched data from database(MS Access) and display it in jTable. But its giving me a null pointer exception.
the code is as given below:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class GuestDetail extends javax.swing.JFrame {
      PreparedStatement ps;
      ResultSet rs;
      Connection conn;
      Statement stmt;
      TableModel tm;
      int sr;
/**
 * Creates new form GuestDetail
 */
public GuestDetail() {
    initComponents();
    try{
    conn = HotelManagement.ConnectDb();
    tm=new DefaultTableModel(4, 4);
    jTable1.setModel(tm);
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}


 private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)         {                                         

  // TODO add your handling code here:
     try{

       System.out.println("Searching Records..");
           String fn=jTextField1.getText();

        System.out.println("searching name="+fn);

      stmt=conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

     //  String query1="SELECT * FROM GuestDetails WHERE FirstName LIKE'fn%'";

      String query="select FirstName,LastName,City,ContactNo from GuestDetails where FirstName= ' "+jTextField1.getText()+" '";

      System.out.println("query:"+query);
              rs.next();
              int rows=rs.getInt(1);
              ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(query);
              Object[][] data=new Object[rows][4];
              Object[] headers={"FirstName","LastName","City","ContactNo"};

              int i=0;
              while(rs.next())
              {
                 int j=0;
                 data[i][j++]=rs.getString(1);
                 data[i][j++]=rs.getString(2);
                 data[i][j++]=rs.getString(3);
                 data[i++][j]=rs.getLong(4);
              }
              DefaultTableModel tm=new DefaultTableModel(data, headers);
             jTable1.setModel(tm);    






   }catch (Exception ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(GuestDetail.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();

   }
```

Comment: can you please post exception stack trace ?

Comment: _the code is as given below_ The code you given us won't even compile. Apart from that, just saying you have a `NullPointerException` is not really helpful. We need to know at which line in the code you post that the `NullPointerException` happened. But if you figured out where the `NullPointerException` occurs, you can probably fix it as well. Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/1076463)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be assuming that the first row and column of the `ResultSet` is the row count. Instead, create an empty `DefaultTableModel` and use the `addRow()` method for each row that you encounter in the `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you should be going to the database from the EDT.  I'm assuming that, since all that activity is in an event handler, it's going to be called as a result of a button click and that it'll be called by the EDT.

You need to put all of the data retrieval and the construction of the "data" array into a Swingworker runnable, and then put the data model creation and installation into the table into the "done" method of the Swingworker.